# looking for example of infinite p-group of nilpotency class 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, p-groups

Is there infinite p-group of nilpotency class 2?
If p=2 or p=3 would be better. and I prefer simple examples

Comment: $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^{(\mathbb N)} \times G$ where $G$ is a finite $p$-group of nilpotency class 2.

Comment: @ user254022 : Is it necessary to take  families with finite support?

Comment: @YassineGuerboussa: No, there's plenty of freedom to pick a different group there. Finite direct products of groups of nilpotency class $\le 2$ have nilpotency class $\le 2$, and finite direct products of $p$-groups are $p$-groups. Since $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^{\mathbb N}$ is an abelian $p$-group, you can also take that for the left factor.

Comment: I just wanted to notice that a direct product of an  arbitrary family of $p$-groups of bounded exponent is a p-group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an infinite field of characteristic $p$, and consider the groupe of upper unitriangular matrices of degree $3$.